# python use of corrcoeff to achieve matlab's corr function

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

After I tried every solution I found online, I must ask here.

I want to achieve the behavior of `matlab's corr` function:
I have 2 matrices A and B.
A's shape: (200, 30000)
B's shape: (200, 1)

in matlab, `corr(A, B)` will return a matrix with size (30000, 1).
when I use `numpy.corrcoef` (or `dask` for better performance) I get a (30001, 30001) matrix which is extremely huge, and a wrong answer.
I tried using argument `rowvar=False` as some answer suggested, but it didnt work as well.

I even tried `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(np.transpose(traces), np.transpose(my_trace), metric='correlation')` which indeed returned a matrix in shape(30000, 1) as expected but the values were differnet then the result in matlab.

I am desperate for a solution for this problem, please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matlab's `corr` by default calculates the correlation of columns of `A` and `B`, while Python's `corrcoef` calculates the correlation of rows within an array(if you pass the function two arrays, it seems it will do the same with vertically stacked arrays). If you do not care about the performance and need to find an easy way to do it, you can stack two arrays horizontally and calculate correlation and get the corresponding elements you would like:

```
correlation = np.corrcoef(np.hstack((B,A)),rowvar=False)[0,1:]
```

But if you care about performance more than simple codes, you would need to implement the `corr` function yourself. (Please comment and I will add it if that is what you are looking for)

***UPDATE***: If you would like to implement `corr` to prevent extra calculations/memory usage, you can calculate correlation using its formula by first normalizing arrays and then multiplying them:

```
A = (A - A.mean(axis=0))/A.std(axis=0)
B = (B - B.mean(axis=0))/B.std(axis=0)
correlation = (np.dot(B.T, A)/B.shape[0])[0]
```

output of sample code:

```
A = np.array([1,2,2,2]).reshape(4,1)
B = np.arange(20).reshape(4,5)

Python: np.corrcoef(np.hstack((A,B)),rowvar=False)[0,1:]

[0.77459667 0.77459667 0.77459667 0.77459667 0.77459667]

Matlab:  corr(A,B)

0.7746    0.7746    0.7746    0.7746    0.7746
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but got a new problem. my process is killed by SIGKILL, because of over memory usage(happened with np.corrcoef before, and even now with dask.corrcoef) maybe an implementation of you will be better(I also dont understand why that happened, with (30000, 30000) matrix i get it but its just (30000, 1) and it is about 240,000 bytes in size but it takes several GB of RAM when I try to write my result to another matrix

Comment: `np.corrcoef` will return a (30,001x30,001) array. I will update my answer with an implementation of correlation. Although a RAM of 8GB+ should be able to do it if you are not doing heavy calculations on the side.

Comment: (30,001x30,001) with each element takes 8 bytes is taking more than 6GB of ram. also, using dask.corrcoef returned array with shape(30000,) as desired

Comment: I have not worked with `dask`, however, I assume numpy calculates the whole `corrceof` first and then we slice it, which means somewhere along the calculations, you will have a (30,001x30,001) matrix in your memory which in turn kills the process. I will update an answer than will not need that much memory in a bit.

Comment: @OrelVaknin please find the added implementation in the post. Hope it helps.

Comment: I got confused between the size of A and B, will it still work?

Comment: Edited the post accordingly. please check out the edited one and if it solved, please go ahead and accept the answer so others find it helpful too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With the following version, you can use get Matlab's `corr` with python's `corrcoef`  :

```
Corr = np.absolute(np.corrcoef(A.T, B.T))
Corr = Corr[0:A.shape[1],-B.shape[1]:]
```